# Can i use Trigger.* in Batch constructor?

Tags: apex, trigger, parameters

This is my batch constructor :

```
public  void RelateContactAccounts() { 
        
    Map<Id, List<Id>> accountContactRelationIdsMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    for (AccountContactRelation accountContactRelation : (List<AccountContactRelation>) Trigger.new) {
        String oldRoles = (Trigger.isUpdate) ? ((AccountContactRelation) Trigger.oldMap.get(accountContactRelation.Id)).Roles : null;

        if (accountContactRelation.Roles != null && accountContactRelation.Roles.contains(Label1) && (Trigger.isInsert ||
                (Trigger.isUpdate && (oldRoles == null || !oldRoles.contains(labelVisibilitePortail))))) {
            if (!accountContactRelationIdsMap.containsKey(accountContactRelation.AccountId)) {
                accountContactRelationIdsMap.put(accountContactRelation.AccountId, new List<Id>());
            }
            accountContactRelationIdsMap.get(accountContactRelation.AccountId).add(accountContactRelation.ContactId);
        }
    }
}
```

My need is to remove **Trigger.*** stuffs - Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in three parameters:

1. `Trigger.isUpdate` as a parameter of type `Boolean`, e.g. `isUpdate`
2. `Trigger.new` as a parameter of type `List<AccountContactRelation>`, e.g. `relations`
3. `Trigger.oldMap` as a parameter of type `Map<Id, AccountContactRelation>`, e.g. `oldRelationsById`

Then call the method passing in those equivalent Trigger context variables to each relevant parameter and switch out the use of the Trigger context variable with the new parameter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116438/discussion-on-answer-by-phil-w-how-can-i-declare-variable-using-apex-parameter).